# how to subtract 2 months from current month?

Tags: 7, datetime

I have used this :

> $date = date("Y-m", strtotime("-2 months"));

and it is gives "2016-12" but what i needed is "2016-11".

Comment: This seems to be an general php question. The question is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163387/how-do-i-subtract-4-months-of-date-today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used :

> $fdate = date('Y-m', strtotime('first day of -2 month'));

Comment: This is working for me

Answer (score 1):

If you try to change format to dmY for example: 
echo date("dmY", strtotime("-2 months"));
You will see that result is 01122016.

You can check comments from this question also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586615/current-date-2-months

And you can check solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058523/php-date-and-strtotime-return-wrong-months-on-31st

Pass second parameter.